# Unable to apply sticky header using flatlist with fixed first column and horizontal rest of the columns

Tags: react-native, sticky, horizontal-scrolling, flatlist, fixed-header-tables

I achieved both fixed first column and rest of the columns with horizontal scroll by using native react flatlist component. But im unable to apply headers sticky.

```
<ScrollView horizontal={false} height={300} nestedScrollEnabled> 
{teamStatsData.fetchingData ? <StatsTableLoader height={500} /> :      
  <View style={{flexDirection:"row"}}>
    {teamStatsData.teamStatsData && 
      <FlatList
        data={teamStatsData.teamStatsData}
        renderItem={renderData2}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.team.id}
        ListHeaderComponent={headersLeft}
        stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}
      />
    }
    {teamStatsData.teamStatsData && 
    <ScrollView horizontal nestedScrollEnabled style={{borderRightWidth:10, borderRightColor:"black"}}>
      <FlatList
        data={teamStatsData.teamStatsData}
        renderItem={selectedPosition.value=="batting" ? renderHitterData : renderPitcherData}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.team.id}        
        scrollEnabled
        ListHeaderComponent={selectedPosition.value=="batting" ? headersHitterRight : headersPitcherRight }
        stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}
      />
    </ScrollView>
    }
  </View>
```

}

Comment: can you please share screen shot of UI, which you want?

Comment: @JatinBhuva https://ibb.co/D8Kjk2Y